# Combining Excel's AND and OR within an IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm trying to combine 'AND' and 'OR' into an IF statement which looks at two cells, and 3 'OR' criteria, but I'm not sure if it's possible. Logic below:

IF cell M2 = "P4", AND cell AB2 = "P3" OR cell AB2 = "P2" OR cell AB2 = "P1", "Elevated", "Not Elevated"

This is as far as I got with regard to an actual formula which doesn't yet incorporate the 'OR' portion:

```
=IF(AND(M2="P4",(AB2="P3")),"Elevated","Not Elevated")
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
= IF(OR(AND(M2 = "P4",AB2 = "P3"),AB2 = "P2",AB2 = "P1"), "Elevated", "Not Elevated")
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment:

```
= IF(M2<>"P4","N/A",IF(OR(AB2={"P1","P2","P3"}),"Elevated","Not Elevated")
```

Comment: I know this is beyond the scope of the original question, but is there any way to build in error handling so that if cell M2 doesn't equal "P4", it throws out "N/A" or something? Right now it's showing 'Elevated' even when cell M2 equals "P3" etc.

Comment: @MarkyMark I assume you mean that you only want to have "N/A" if `M2!="P4"` **and** `AB2="P3"`?

Comment: So, in columns M and AB, the value could be P1, P2, P3, or P4. With the formula above, when M is NOT P4, but AB is still lower than whatever's in M, it marks it as "Elevated" (I have 2 additional formulas to deal with P3s and P2s). I was thinking along the lines of including a NOT clause in the formula that would account for M2 NOT being P4, then it would throw out "N/A" or something along those lines. Let me know if that makes sense

Comment: Fantastic, much appreciated!